# Count the number of rows of a CSV file, with d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose I have this CSV file

```
Day,What
2013-10-27,Apple
2013-10-27,Cake
2013-10-27,Apple
2013-10-28,Apple
2013-10-28,Apple
2013-10-28,Blueberry
2013-10-28,Orange
```

I would like to drawn with D3.js a time-series graph. All I need to do is to display the sum of the number of rows for each day. As an example, the 27 of November should have 3 as value, the 28th should have 4.

Is there a way I can archive it? I've been trying to create a new dataset out of the CSV one with no positive results.

```
var dataset;

d3.csv("data.csv", function(d) {
  return {
    Day: new Date(d.Day),
    What: d.What
  };
}, 

function(error, rows) {
    dataset = rows;
    // I SUPPOSE THE FUNCTION THAT GENERATE THE NEW DATASET SHOULD GO THERE     
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the fast lookup of JavaScript Object properties as an index while you accumulate your counts:

```
var counts = {};
rows.forEach(function(r) {
    if (!counts[r.Day]) {
        counts[r.Day] = 0;
    }
    counts[r.Day]++;
});
```

Then you'll need to convert this back into an array so you can use it with D3:

```
var data = [];
Object.keys(counts).forEach(function(key) {
    data.push({
        day: key,
        count: counts[key]
    });
});
```

I'm assuming here that you want to ignore the "What" column because you only talked about aggregating a count of days and there are different "What" values for the same day.  If you want to consider "What" while you count you can just build it into the key of your original `counts` object (`r.Day + r.What`).

EDIT:  Based on comment, adding the code with a compound key.

```
var counts = {};
rows.forEach(function(r) {
    var key = r.Day + r.What;
    if (!counts[key]) {
        counts[key] = {
           day: r.Day,
           what: r.What,
           count: 0
        };
    }
    counts[key].count++;
});

var data = [];
Object.keys(counts).forEach(function(key) {
    data.push(counts[key]);
});
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks. Just one more question: I've added the +r.What and yes, it's very useful to create separate count for each category based on the day, but at that point the date/key of the new array is not a date anymore (since it's chained with r.What). Is there a way — in the data.push({}); bit — to keep them separate, in order to keep a readable correctly formatted date, and have a count and a "category"?

Comment: Yeah, if you use both properties as a compound key you can't use the key as the "day" value anymore.  But you can fix that by making the properties in `counts` objects themselves.  Then you can just copy the object references over into an array.  I've updated the answer with some sample code showing this.

Answer (score 0):

A function along these lines should do the trick. I can't test it out at a computer at the moment so let me know if it doesn't work as I may have made a typo!

```
function createNewArray(dataset) {
  var lastDate = dataset[0].Date;  // initialise
  var count = 0;
  var newArray = new Array();
  for (var i = 0; i < dataset.length; i++) {
      if (dataset[i].Date != lastDate || i == dataset.length-1) {
          // on a new day (or the final row), so push value and reset count variable
          newArray.push({ Day: lastDate, Count: count });
          count = 0;
      }        
      count++;        
      lastDate = dataset[i].Date;
  }
  return newArray;
}
```